# My login form doesn't work in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I'm working on my portfolio and I'm trying to add a form for me to login to use my CMS. I'm using Symfony 2. Here is the step I took before having my problem (I'm going to explain it latter).

First, I read the documentation on security on the Symfony website (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html). At this point, it works, If I try to access any url that have admin/ before it, it ask me a usename and a password. The username and password that I enter work and it is encrypted. So far everything work perfectly.

Here is my configuration at this point:

Router of my app:

```
public:
    resource: "@PublicBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

admin:
    resource: "@AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin

app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Router of my admin bundle:

```
admin:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Admin:index }

chemin_test:
    path:     /test
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Admin:test }
```

My security.ynk file:

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: 
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Now here comes the part where it doesn't work. I read [the chapter on how to change the popup menu for a real form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html). Here are the files that changed:

Security.yml:

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /admin/
                check_path: /admin/login_check

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: 
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The router of my admin bundle:

```
admin:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Securite:login }

admin_login_check:
    path:     /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Securite:loginCheck }

chemin_test:
    path:     /test
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Admin:test }
```

My admin and security controllers:

Admin:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
       return new Response('<html><body>Hello!</body></html>');
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
       return new Response('<html><body>Hello!</body></html>');
    }
}
```

Security:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class SecuriteController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        //Va chercher l'utilitaire pour l'authentification
        $utilitaireAuthentification = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        //Va chercher l'erreur de connexion si il y en a une
        $erreur = $utilitaireAuthentification->getLastAuthenticationError();

        //Dernier nom d'utilisateur entrer dans le formulaire
        $dernierUtilisateur = $utilitaireAuthentification->getLastUsername();

        //Affiche le formulaire
        return $this->render('AdminBundle::connexion.html.twig',array(
                                                                    'dernier_utilisateur'=>$dernierUtilisateur,
                                                                    'erreur'=>$erreur
                                                                ));
    }

    public function loginCheckAction()
    {
       
    }
}
```

My form template:

```
{% extends  "::base.html.twig"%}
{% block contenu_body %}

    {% if erreur %}
        <div>{{ erreur.messageKey|trans(erreur.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('admin_login_check') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ dernier_utilisateur }}" />

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

        {#
            If you want to control the URL the user
            is redirected to on success (more details below)
            <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
        #}

        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

It's at this point that my problem happens.

If I try to go to localhost/portfolio/web/app_dev.php/admin, it load for a while and then, it tells me

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is here :

```
    default:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /admin/
            check_path: /admin/login_check
```

login and login_check path shouldn't be under admin since only logged in users can go to pages under /admin... 
So what happens is that you try to go to a /admin page it will load forever trying to go to /admin/login but he is not allowed since the user is not logged in and keep on trying.. until he throws the error that it is an infinite loop.

give login path the login route you have and check_path login_check.

```
    default:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login_route
            check_path: login_check
```

Comment: I tried your solution and I changed the name of my route for:
login_route:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Securite:login }

login_check:
    path:     /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Securite:loginCheck }
I tdidn't work, it still gives me the same problem

Comment: maybe your routing.yml is under /admin for the login_route and login_check?

Comment: I found the solution. Like you said, my login_route and login_check were after /admin, so ot was continually redirecting since I told the security field to redirect if he found admin/. The solution was juste to have login and login_check to not be after admin/. In my case, I decided to make a connexion bundle juste for the securityController and the login form. Thanks for your help, it's your hints that allow me to truly understand my problem!